# Flutter: IconButton with filled background using CircleBorder - How to set the size

Tags: flutter

```
 Container(
                      child: Center(
                        child: Ink(
                          decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
                            color: Colors.lightGreen,
                            shape: CircleBorder(),
                          ),
                          child: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                            color: Colors.white,
                            onPressed: () {},
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text('KG : $_volume'),
                    Container(
                      width: 40,
                      height: 40,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Ink(
                          decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
                            color: Colors.lightGreen,
                            shape: CircleBorder(),
                          ),
                          child: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                            color: Colors.white,
                            onPressed: () {},
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

This creates IconButton with filled background as shiwn in the image attached.[image]

I want to reduce the size of the circle (CircleBorder) here. How do I do it effectively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `IconButton` widgets have default padding try to remove it will work

Try this way

```
Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: 40,
              height: 40,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: (){

                },
                child: Ink(
                    decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
                      color: Colors.lightGreen,
                      shape: CircleBorder(),
                    ),
                    child: Icon(Icons.add,color: Colors.white,)
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Text('KG : 5'),
            Container(
              width: 40,
              height: 40,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: (){

                },
                child: Ink(
                    decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
                      color: Colors.lightGreen,
                      shape: CircleBorder(),
                    ),
                    child: Icon(Icons.add,color: Colors.white,)
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Another way

```
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: 40,
              height: 40,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle,
              color: Colors.lightGreen),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  debugPrint('Clicked');
                },
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Text('KG : 5'),
            Container(
              width: 40,
              height: 40,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  color: Colors.lightGreen),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  debugPrint('Clicked');
                },
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**IconButton** with **Circle** Filled Background [image: Circle Button Icon]

```
Container(
  width: 30,
  height: 30,
  decoration: ShapeDecoration(
      shape: CircleBorder(),
      color: const Color(0xFFf6a265),
  ),
  child: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      debugPrint('onTap');
    },
    child: Icon(
      Icons.add,
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
  ),
)
```

**IconButton** with **Box** Filled Background [image: Box Button Icon]

```
Container(
  width: 30,
  height: 30,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
      color: const Color(0xFFf6a265),
      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(5))
  ),
  child: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      debugPrint('onTap');
    },
    child: Icon(
      Icons.add,
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
  ),
)
```